# How can remove the "0" and "+" from the phone number in php

Tags: php, whatsapp

The "0" and "+" from the phone number must be removed. And also need to turn the phone number into a WhatsApp link.

Example : +971 561545785

Output : https://wa.me/971561545785

i have tried like this,

$countryCode = "+971";

$phone_number = "561545785";

$newNumber = preg_replace('/^0+?/', 'https://wa.me/'.$countryCode,
$phone_number);

But this only removing the zero from. how can i remove 0 and + from phone number and save a WhatsApp link.

Comment: If that country has `9` digit phone numbers, just concatenate last `9` digits of phone number to country-code `"+971"` & whatapp link-prefix `"https://wa.me/971"`

Answer (score 0):

Use options inside square brackets

```
/^[0+]?/
```